# Convert unicode string to int or long

Tags: java

For some purpose, I want to convert the `String` to my Unicode to `int` or `long` or `double`. I just need a number. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get primitive values, use :

```
Integer.parseInt("12");
Long.parseLong("1024");
Double.parseDouble("1.52");
```

If you want to get objects corresponding to these values (Integer object, Long object, etc), use :

```
Integer.valueOf("12");
Long.valueOf("1024");
Double.valueOf("4.17");
```